# Using Fiddler2 HTTP request inspector with an Android device

Tags: android, http, proxy, httprequest, fiddler

For a project working I need to inspect the HTTP requests sent and received from my Android device. I'm using this tool Fiddler2 to monitor the traffic. In order to get it working I had to pass the traffic through a proxy. Now my phone is a Huawei U8180. Its runs Android 2.2 so it doesn't have a direct way to proxy settings. I used this app called [Proxy Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lechucksoftware.proxy.proxysettings) to gain access to set the proxy settings.

It almost works. I can see the traffic say, if I navigate to a website using the proxy web browser in that app (The app comes with a proxy browser). But **not** using my phone's normal browser. Neither I can see any HTTP requests sent by any of my apps installed in my device.

If anyone has any experience using Fiddler2 with Android, I'd really appreciate your input. I'm open to try any other alternatives to accomplish this if you got any.

Thanks.

Comment: what about using the emulator to look at the requests?

Comment: there is an option to set a proxy server in Settings > Wireless and Network Settings on android 2.2

Answer (score 1):

Typically, Android users will use a tool like `iptables` to capture traffic from apps that don't support a proxy setting. This has some implications for HTTPS decryption; see the Fiddler Discussion Group (Help > Fiddler Community) for discussion of how to adjust Fiddler's HTTPS settings to accommodate iptables-redirected HTTPS connections.